# Generic parameter extending a record does not infer key type constraint

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics, record, type-inference

When creating a `Record`, the `keyof` correctly determines its key type. But when a generic parameter extends the Record, the key type constraint is not inferred:

```
export type Dictionary<K extends number | string, V> = Partial<Record<K, V>>;

type MyDict = Dictionary<string, any>;
type Key = keyof MyDict; // Key correctly infered as string;

const myFunc = <D extends MyDict>(dict: D) => {
  // keyof D incorrectly infered as string | number | symbol 
  type OtherDict = Dictionary<keyof D, number>; 
};
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBLAxjDEB2AhlIgDwDScoMw+AJgM5z4CuAtgEbBRwA+cDGFAz4A5gBo4ANQB8cALxwACsVyEANqQBKwLNDoVJsmQG4AsAChLSFHACyiTDgXpsuAsTKDhYyYXyIptbIqOTAiC4A1uEQAGb2jm4mcAD0KXBhEXpQULow6hEisdzAdHCETN4iouZWFnr4gnBsiABiLPhYLqRoVCA09EwOTjAyABR0bgBc6ACUCnIA3pZwCCFwAPIwABbcIy4jeEQkpNGIceiSrJzcpqnpZxe9Itm5OAVwRSVlFQJC1XxmOwuDx+AxEJwIOo4JYAL61IA)

Is there a way to get around this, and apply the constraint without having to assert the type of every `keyof D` instance?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is technically correct that `D` might have `symbol`-valued keys.  Object types in TypeScript are open/extendable and not closed/exact.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for a feature request for exact types) You can add a property to an object type and still conform to that object type.  Here is an example, however unlikely it might be:

```
const s = Symbol("symbol");
interface YourDict extends MyDict {
  [s]: number;
}
const d: YourDict = { [s]: 123 };
myFunc(d);
```

The type `YourDict` is definitely an extension of `MyDict`, and it has a `symbol`-valued key.  And the call to `myFunc()` accepts a value of type `YourDict`.  Since `D` may have any keys whatsoever, the compiler balks at using `keyof D` in a place constrained to `string | number`.

---

The easiest way around this issue without trying to tease apart `keyof D` to exclude `symbol`, is to just allow `symbol` keys in your `Dictionary`:

```
export type Dictionary<K extends PropertyKey, V> = Partial<Record<K, V>>;
```

The type `PropertyKey` is a [built in utility type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a26acf454088bfab8956f44e6254e167a91f0f9e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L105) synonymous with `string | number | symbol`.  This clears up the error:

```
const myFunc = <D extends MyDict>(dict: D) => {
  type OtherDict = Dictionary<keyof D, number>; // okay
};
```

My guess is that this is probably sufficient for your needs, since I doubt you want to spend much time worrying about `symbol` keys at all.  If you have some important reason to prohibit `symbol` or other keys, there are steps you can take, but the open types of TypeScript's type system makes this a bit tricky, so I wouldn't recommend it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBLAxjDEB2AhlIgDwDScoMw+AJgM5wAKUEKsi5wiANHADUAfHAC8LYrkIAbUgCVgWaHQr9hQgNwBYAFC6kKOAFlEmHGPTZcBYmQYwoGfAHN+hfIk37kqbogsA1jwQAGbGplYacAD00XB+cEpQUIow0v5OIcApdHCETPaOLtp6Okr49nAAtogAYgCu+FgWpGhUIDT0TCZmMEIAFHRWAFzoAJRiIgDeunAIPnAA8jAAFtm9Fr14RCSkQYih6Pz49VUARtmaMXEQAYSIugC+JbrllUziAMqI5xDS-QAiBg-M5-AFjEpOGhQEKELCoACaEHqUA21FojHCGxmOjmAG0GABdUYnc7ZEqPV4ESp0UZIlEbcRTOAE4lwACMACYAMxwZ66GoNJqDCG6XRAA)